# React global variable not being updated inside function that passing to children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that having some props passing from grandparent component and I am using one prop (object) and pass the value of that object to children component as props. I also pass a function to child component in order to get the updated value back from child component.

ParentComponent.js

```
const ParentComponent = props => {

    const { record, saveRecord } = props;

    const editedRecord = {...record}



    const handleRecordValues = (name, value) => {
       editedRecord[name] = value;
    };

...
    const content = <div>
       <ChildComponent name={record.name} value={record.value} setValue={handleRecordValues} />
       <Button onClick={() => saveRecord(editedRecord)} />
    </div>

    return content;
}
```

ChildrenComponent.js

```
const ChildComponent = props => {

    const { name, value, setValue } = props;
    const [input, setInput] = useState(value);

    const handleChange = (e, text) => {
        setInput(text);
        setValue(name, value);
    }


    return <TextField value={input} onChange={handleChange}/>
}
```

Above are the sample components I have. The issue is when I pass the editedRecord to saveRecord func to grandparent component the editedRecord is always the same as record as it is copied from record and value is not updated for that variable. I expect the editedRecord being updated by the handleRecordValues func.

For example, the record that I get is {}. And I create a new const editedRecord which is also {}.
After I input some value from ChildComponent the editedRecord should be updated to {name: value}. However when I click on Button in ParentComponent the editedRecord parameter is still {}.

**Updated**
Instead of using const I use

```
const [editedRecord, setEditedRecord] = useState(record);

const handleRecordValues = (name, value) => {

        const newRecord = {
            ...editedRecord
        };
        newRecord[name] = value;
        setEditedRecord(newRecord);
    };
```

Now the editedRecord value got updated but another issue came up: 
when I have multiple  components as child components it only update the last one entry I have entered.

Comment: this is why React implements `state`, in your case, instead of create  `editedRecord` constant, use `useState`.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia I tried to use setState for editedRecord. But it was still not working as expected.

Comment: When you have multiple child components, each needs its own record.

Comment: In case you weren't aware (and I only say this because you're new here) you shouldn't try to ask two questions in a single Stack Overflow post.  Instead, you should accept whichever answer best answered your original question (if any did), and then create a new post (with new/relevant code samples) for your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setValue`/`handleRecordValues` function changes a variable ... but React has no way of knowing when that variable changes.

To let React know, you have to call `saveRecord(editedRecord)` after you make the change, or in other words you have to invoke a state-setting function, so that React knows about the change.

In general in React, if you don't change context/state/props (and for context/state, that means doing so using the appropriate React functions), React can't know to re-render your components in response.  This means that any data that your components depend on to render needs to be changed via one of those three mechanisms, not just via ordinary Javascript, ie. `a.b = c`.

**EDIT:** To clarify a point in the comments.  When you make a state variable:

```
const [myState, myStateSetter] = useState('');
```

there is nothing "magic" about `myState`; it's just another JS variable.  Javascript doesn't give React any way to know when that variable changes, so if you just do:

```
 myState = 4;
```

React has no idea that you did so.  It only knows that it changed **if** you tell it that it changed ... ie. if you call:

```
myStateSetter(4);
```

Comment: Sorry I am not following you..Everytime I update the input value that setValue should be invoked right? And the editedRecord value should be updated. Then When I click on button saveRecord would be invoked.

Comment: You are doing `editedRecord[name] = value;`.  That doesn't work in React, because React is not magic: it plays by the rules of Javascript, and Javascript doesn't give you a way to magically know when a variable changes.  The only way React can know about the change (the same as any other code in JS) is if you call a React state-(or context-) setting function, like the one generated by `useState` (or you change which `props` are passed to a child component).

Comment: P.S. For any data that *doesn't* affect how your components render, you *can* still use plain old Javascript.  This rule only applies to component-rendering-dependent data (ie. when you want to see the page change when the data changes).  In fact, you can think of that as a rule you can use to decide "should I make a normal JS variable or a state variable?": the answer is the answer to "does the data impact component rendering?"

Comment: I am not using React state-setting function for editedRecord because I don't think editedRecord is component-rendering-dependent data. Maybe I am wrong? can you please see my update?

Comment: A separate issue really warrants a separate (Stack Overflow) question.  I'd need to see the code of those other components, but presumably you *aren't* passing the changed value to them, or else they *would* update automatically, because again changing `props` is one of the three ways React *can* know about changes.

Comment: Sorry for this. I will create a new question.

Comment: No need to apologize :) We all started out new once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would alter the parent component to make everything work with react. The main issue you were having is that react needs to know that a change has occurred, so we need to set up the values as state/set state.

```
const ParentComponent = props => {

    const { record, saveRecord } = props;
    const [editedRecord,setEditedRecord] = useState(record);
    useEffect(()=>{
        //This sets the record straight whenever the parent passes a new record.
        //You'd need to make sure the record is referentially stable when it isn't being updated, though
        setEditedRecord(record);
    },[record])

    const handleRecordValues = (name, value) => {
        setEditedRecord(record=>{...record,[name]:value});
    };

...
    const content = <div>
       <ChildComponent name={editedRecord.name} value={editedRecord.value} setValue={handleRecordValues} />
       <Button onClick={() => saveRecord(editedRecord)} />
    </div>

    return content;
}
```

Comment: I think this would work when I only have one input child component. If I have multiple components I only get the update from the last one.